How to make sure one suite results don't overwrite the other ones?
I have a couple batch files which kick off certain sets of tests at different times throughout the day:

Full regression (over 1000 tests) - kicks off at 9PM

npx playwright test --grep "@daily" --reporter=junit


Smoke Tests - which kick off at 7AM and run every hour on the hour

npx playwright test --grep "@smoke" --reporter=".\tests\Logging\splunkreporter.ts"



With over 1000 tests full regression, using playwright's --last-failed flag is a huge help, due to test flakiness.
The problem is, once the smoke tests kick off at 7AM, that overwrites everything in the test-results directory including the .last-run.json file, the results file, and all the folders with video, etc...  And therefore the results from the full regression are gone.
I hadn't considered this problem until both were finally running; especially since the smoke tests use a custom reporter which publish the test results to a splunk server.
Is there a good way to disable overwriting previous run logs in our test-results directory when using a customer reporter?  Or does anyone else have any other recommendations to handle this situation?

There is nothing wrong with this question. Please don't suggest to close without any strong reasons.We are users community , we should help each other.

I had a similar situation where we were smoke testing multiple web sites and wanted to group the results together. I ended up just redirecting the results to a different folder that was unique for each web site.  I did this by setting the environment variable PLAYWRIGHT_HTML_REPORT (which sets the output directory for the HTML reporter), before each web sites had its tests run.
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#junit-reporter shows a list of all the environment variables you can set/change for jUnit.  Some of them deal with output.

It will still create the issue as the "outputDir" will still remain the same which is the source for all kind of html third party generated  reports.

Configure Suite Results to Save in Different Folders
We can configure our test results to be saved in different folders for each suite using the outputDir property in your test configuration under different project configurations. Here's how we can do it:
import { defineConfig} from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'suite1',
      testDir: './tests/suite1',
      outputDir: './results/suite1', // Results for suite1
    },
    {
      name: 'suite2',
      testDir: './tests/suite2',
      outputDir: './results/suite2', // Results for suite2
    },
  ]
 
});

and can run a specific suite like below:
npx playwright test --project=suite1

